# sed - have several pass on the same file in one sed script

Tags: sed

In sed documentation, we read that "sed works by  making only one  pass over  the input(s)".

I would like to write a sed script (to be run like this : `sed -f my_script.sed`), that performs several operations including on the operations that were performed earlier in the script.

Is it possible to perform a second (or n-th) pass on the edited stream content ?

e.g. :

- initial stream content :

`titi`

- stream content after first pass :

```
/titi/ i (
/titi/ a )
```

```bsh
$ cat test.txt
(
titi
)
```

- after another pass :

```
s/(/{/g
s/)/}/g
```

I would like the output to be

```
$ cat test.txt
{
titi
}
```

This is just an example to show that i'd like to perform stream editions that have effects on previous commands inside a single `.sed` script.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` only gets one pass over the input stream.  This is specifically stated in the man page (at least, on Fedora 33, anyway).

Whenever I have to do something like this, I pipe the output of `sed` into a second instance of `sed` to do the subsequent edits.